# I want to select a attribute [jquery]

Tags: jquery

This is the html code:

```
<input type="submit" value="ssss" name="0"/>
<input type="submit" value="ss" name="1"/>
```

I want to obtain the value in the "name" attribute and I use this

```
var i=$('#input[type=submit]').attr("name");
alert(i);
```

This is when I match the input to function:

```
<input type="submit" value="O"
                        name="<?php echo $v[$i]['t] ?>"
                        onclick="javascript:test_parent();" />
```

But it prints undefined. Anyone can help me?

Comment: remove `#` from selector

Comment: The API should be the first thing you go to in cases like this: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @Amit Soni I remove #. It doesn't work!

Comment: @Fuffy do you have any other `input` with `type='submit'` within your code before this `input` element ??

Comment: No. I edit my question so you can see how I call

Comment: first of all, u missed  `'` after `t` and second, i think you need to echo it like `echo $v[$i]['t'];`

Comment: @AmitSoni I correct with your suggest but I print "undefined"

Comment: please post `PHP` code as well

Comment: @Fuffy, please check the edit on my answer. You probably still have that `#` in your selector too. Did you check if it's `var i=$('input[type=submit]').attr("name");` now?

Comment: I edit with your suggest... I think the error is when I give at the attribute name the value: name="<?php echo $v[$i]['t] ?>" because if i print the value attribute it prints the correct value but when I print the name attribute I obtain "undefined"

Comment: inspect `input` element using chrome `developer tool` & check if `name` attribute is correctly set or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an octothorp in your selector: `$('#input[type=submit]')`.

The octothorp `#` is used to select id's. any element is selected without any special characters attached to the start: `body`, `html`, `input`, `a`, `select` etcetera.

Change your selector to:

```
var i=$('input[type=submit]').attr("name");
```

and it will work.

Please take a look at [the following page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) while you're at it.

**EDIT:** Try adding an ID to the submit buttons, then select the jQuery object with that ID and apply your code to that. Here's an example!

```js
$('#span0').text($('#submit0').attr("name"));
$('#span1').text($('#submit1').attr("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="submit0" type="submit" value="ssss" name="0"/>
<input id="submit1" type="submit" value="ss" name="1"/>

<div>The value of button 'ssss' is <span id="span0"></span></div>
<div>The value of button 'ss' is <span id="span1"></span></div>
```

Comment: I will edit my answer. Maybe you should add an ID to your submit buttons. I'l show you in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector, add double quotes around type value and remove `#`:

```
var i=$('input[type="submit"]').attr("name");
```

Also you have 2 inputs that this selector can find. You could be more specific, for example to find second one use `:eq()` selector:

```
var i=$('input[type="submit"]:eq(1)').attr("name");
```